# Derivative where the variable is a function, e.g. D[x^4,x^2]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I express in MMA a derivative if the variable is a function?

Example:

The first derivative of $x^4$ with respect to $x^2$, would be
$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}{x^4}}{\mathrm{d}{x^2}}=2x^2$ ?

`D[x^4,x^2]`
returns "*x^2 is not a valid variable.*"

In general I am interested in the $n^{th}$ derivative with respect to $x$ for $f(x,n)=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n} e^{-x^2}$
where $x$ can be any function.

Comment: `n! SeriesCoefficient[Exp[-t^2], {t, x, n}, Assumptions -> n >= 0]` for the last q.

Comment: See [`ResourceFunction["ChainD"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ChainD/) where you can do `ResourceFunction["ChainD"][x^4, x^2]` giving result: `2 x^2`